# Java servlet does not work, url mapping issue

Tags: java, servlets

If I made a stupid mistake and asking a stupid question then my apologize. I have a servlet called HelloWorld - it is a simple servlet that implements the Servlet interface that is part of "1stapp" project. Its code is the following:

```
 import java.io.IOException;
 import java.io.PrintWriter;
 import javax.servlet.ServletException;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
 import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
 import javax.servlet.*;
 public class helloworld implements Servlet
 {
     private ServletConfig config;
     public void init(ServletConfig config) 
        throws ServletException {
         this.config=config;
     }
     public void destroy(){}
     public ServletConfig getServletConfig() {
         return config;
     }
     public String getServletInfo() {
         return "this is simple hello World Servlet";
     }
     public void service(ServletRequest request, ServletResponse response)
             throws ServletException, IOException {
         response.setContentType("text/html");
         PrintWriter out=response.getWriter();
         out.println("<html><head>");
         out.println("<title>Simple Servlet</title>");
         out.println("</head>");
         out.println("<body>");
         out.println("<h1>Hello, World</h1>");
         out.println("</body></html>");
         out.close();
      }
  }
```

The HelloWorld servlet was successfully compiled into `classes` directory within `WEB-INF`. The deployment descriptor is the following:

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
  <!DOCTYPE web-app PUBLIC "-//Sun Microsystems, Inc.//DTD Web Application 2.2//EN" 
          "http://java.sun.com/j2ee/dtds/web-app_2.2.dtd">
  <web-app>
        <servlet>
             <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
             <servlet-class>helloworld</servlet-class>
        </servlet>

        <servlet-mapping>
             <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
             <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
        </servlet-mapping>
  </web-app>
```

Now, when I type `localhost:8080/1stapp/hello` firefox geves me problem loading page message. Can anybody say what i did wrong?

Comment: Can you please add the error message and the missing part of your `web.xml`

Comment: Can you add what exact error Firefox is displaying.

Comment: Do you specifically need the web.xml? it works without that.

Comment: It is just "Unbale to connect. FIrefox can't estableish a connection to the server at localhost:8080" message

Comment: Try to browse this url `localhost:8080`. Whats then browser says...

Comment: If firefox says it can't connect than the WebContainer / Tomcat is either not running or your application was not deployed correctly. Have a look at the Tomcat (whatever WebContainer you are using) log files and the console. What's also possible is that the container is listening to a port other than 8080.

Comment: I have that feeling too

Answer (score 1):

There seem to be least three issues

Classes are searched in `WEB-INF/classes` rather than in `WEB-INF`

Use the `HttpServlet` instead of the generic `Servlet`

Overwrite the `doXXX` methods of the `HttpServlet` and not the generic `service` method. The `service` method dispatches to the corresponding `doXXX` method

Comment: what I am doing now is trying to understand simple servet interface implmentation

Comment: If u look carefully at my fist post, I wrote I complied the class file into classes subdirectory of web-inf

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way to map Servlet in `web.xml`

First of all you have to declare your Servlet in web.xml as below

```
<servlet>
        <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>HelloWorld</servlet-class>
</servlet>
```

Then map your URL pattern to the Servlet as

```
<servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>hello</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/hello</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
```

And you better extend HttpServlet rather than Servlet. HttpServlet is the convenient class to work with HTTP protocol.

Change your Servlet class as below.

```
public class HelloWorld extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {

        response.setContentType("text/html");
        PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();
        out.println("<html><head>");
        out.println("<title>Simple Servlet</title>");
        out.println("</head>");
        out.println("<body>");
        out.println("<h1>Hello, World</h1>");
        out.println("</body></html>");
        out.close();
    }
}
```

In addition your Servlet class name should be HelloWorld instead of helloWorld.

Comment: I did not use any package, I just wrote HelloWorld.java  put servlet code there and compiled into classes directory

Comment: Okay, if you dont have any package thats fine (answer edited). To be specific you need to extend HttpServlet instead of implementing Servlet interface.

Comment: That is the point I am trying to understand. For web pages do i need to extend httpservlet or it will work with any class implementing servlet interface. Can u tell me about that?

Comment: apart from extending http servlet, your servlet mapping is exactly the same as mine

Comment: Okay thats an exact question now. Yes. It should work. I tested your code in my context and It runs as expected. though I dont know what exact error firefox giving u. Could u try with another browsers and make it sure your localhost:8080/ is running and Its not the error about your tomcat configuration.